# Binary "[" error on structure while using for function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a Q3BSP map information debugger.

I'm stuck at texture debugger part, this is the code used in that part:

```
for( i = 0; i < nTextures; i++ ) {
    printf( "Texture id %d\n", i );
    printf( "\tTexture name %s\n", Texture[i].name );
    printf( "\tTexture flags %d\n", Texture[i].flags );
    printf( "\tTexture contents %d\n", Texture[i].contents );
}
```

But this kind error appears to show up:

> error C2676: binary '[' : 'Q3BSPTexture' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Here is the Q3BSPTexture structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char        name[64];      // Texture name. 
    int         flags;         // Surface flags.
    int         contents;      // Surface contents
} Q3BSPTexture;
```

I'm suspecting that the structure hasn't the limit setted like char **[32]**

But I like to hear solution from professionals!

Comment: `Texture` is a single `Q2BSPTexture`, not a pointer or array, so saying `Texture[i]` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yeah, just kill the indexing and you're good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown us the definition of `Texture`.

You're treating `Texture` as an array of `Q2BSPTezture`s. Apparently it's a single `Q2BSPTezture` object, so indexing it doesn't make sense. You probably just need to declare it as an array, or perhaps as a pointer to the first element of an array that you the need to allocate.

Also, the error message implies that you're compiling C++, not C (in C it wouldn't be possible for the type to define any operators).

Comment: The Texture is:
fseek( fp, lumps[kTextures].offset, SEEK_SET );
   for ( i = 0; i < nTextures; i++ ) {
       Q3BSPTexture Texture;
  
    fread( &Texture, 1, sizeof( Q3BSPTexture ), fp );
   }

Comment: @GenertOrginaal: Please edit that into your question. You're reading multiple times into the same `Texture` object, clobbering the previous value each time. That's fine if you only need one at a time, but you can't loop over them after reading them.